# Manually created subfolder from /src is missing in /dist when building

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I created a subfolder in `/src` called `/libs`. When I run `npm run build`, the subfolder isn't included in `/dist`.

I'm assuming that I have to modify a build script? If so, which file would that be?

**Edit #1**

This all stems from trying to require a custom module located in `src/libs` from my controller. I've tried various patterns: `../libs/module_name`, `./libs/module_name`. The only way to have it work was to hard code the path from the root (i.e. `/home/me/app/src/libs/module_name`).

If I do: `console.log(__dirname)` in the controller that is attempting to require the module from `/lib`, I see a reference to `/dist`. I went looking into `/dist` and `/libs` wasn't there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lb-tsc` is a thin wrapper for TypeScript compiler (`tsc`), you can find the source in [loopback-next:packages/build/bin/compile-package.js](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/3221d9faed0c5dbc5da8bfc65cad7992f1b91f41/packages/build/bin/compile-package.js)

Among other options, it provides a new flag `--copy-resources` to copy non-TypeScript files from `src` to `dist`. I think it may work equally well (if not better) as your `cp -r` solution.

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "lb-tsc es2017 --outDir dist --copy-resources"
    ...
}
```

Personally, I would use a different solution:

- use `src` only for TypeScript files to be compiled
- put JavaScript sources and other files into a different directory, e.g. `lib` (instead of `src/lib`).

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a colleague, I figured it out. In `package.json`, I appended a copy command to bring the `libs` folder into `dist` in the build section.

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "lb-tsc es2017 --outDir dist && cp -r src/libs dist",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Nest CLI, please note that it also does not automatically move your "assets" (non-TS files) to the dist folder during the build process.

For these non-TS files you just need to add them to the `"compilerOptions": {}`
property in the `nest-cli.json` file.

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": ["**/myfolder/**"]
    ...
    }
```

- The syntax `"**/father-folder/**"` causes all folders & files in `myfolder` to be included in the distribution folder (`dist`)
- My resource for this was from [Derryl Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673191/12991445)
- Link to NestJS documentation on assets : [Link...](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#assets)