# How to copy non-ts files to dist when building typescript?

Tags: typescript, build, nestjs

I have Mail module in folder with this structure:

```
- Mail
  - templates
      - <Handlebars files>
  - mail.module.ts
```

When I build (compile) TypeScript project, my `template` folder is not included in `build` folder.
How to move those kind of files into `dist` when building?

Is it different for development vs production builds?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can also do this by adding an asset property in the nest-cli.json as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#assets).

For your case, you can try something like this:

```
"assets":["**/Mail/templates/*"]
```

Or if your templates all have a specific filetype (I am assuming its called .template), this should also work:

```
"assets":["**/*.template"]
```

The 2nd example will copy all files of type .template from all sub directories to your dist folder with the same folder structure when you run a nest build. Similarly, you can use this to copy any filetype of your choice (.json, .proto, etc) by replacing .template in the glob pattern.

Comment: just to mention, that `"assets":["**/Mail/templates/*"]` should be placed inside `compilerOptions` object

Comment: Very important, thanks!

Answer (score 22):

TS compiler doesn't handle files that are other than TypeScript or JS (e.g. `.ts`, `.js`, `.tsx`, etc.).

One way of doing it, just running `cp` to copy those files after you compile NestJS. In your `package.json` replace the line

```js
"build": "nest build",
```

with

```js
"build": "nest build && cp ./Mail/templates ./build",
```

Ideally, I would switch to Webpack (or similar) to transpile TypeScript and copy artifacts. NestJs has a basic example on how to build with Webpack [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/08-webpack). To extend it to have a "copy" phase, install `copy-webpack-plugin` npm package and add those additions in webpack config file:

```js
const copyFiles = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
// ... omitted for abbreviation

module.exports = function(options) {
   return {
   // ... omitted for abbreviation
   ,
    plugins: [
      // ... omitted for abbreviation
      new copyFiles([
            { from: 'Mail/templates', to: 'templates' }
        ])
    ]
}
```

Comment: FYI but cp is not necessarily cross platform compatible.

Comment: It is not, this is why I thought webpack is a better option

Answer (score 20):

A quick fix for your scenario would be to:

1. `npm install --save-dev copyfiles`
2. Modify your package.json so it includes a new script:

   `"postbundle": "copyfiles -u 1 src/**/*.template dist/"`
3. Add or update your bundle script so it matches:

   `"bundle": "tsc"`

Another more advanced approach would be use to babel or webpack for compile work

Answer (score 8):

I was struggling with the same problem, and then created [typescript-cp](https://github.com/body-builder/typescript-cp).

It detects the source and output directories based on your project's tsconfig.json (using typescript's own config parser, to work as smooth as possible) and copies the non-TS files to the outDir.

It has a very basic CLI, with similar arguments to typescript's tsc, but this is `tscp`. It also supports package references.

```sh
# Copy
$ tscp

# Copy for TS project references
$ tscp -b

# Watcher
$ tscp -w

# Watcher for TS project references
$ tscp -b -w

# Custom compiler settings
$ tscp -p tsconfig.production.json

# Help
$ tscp -h
```

Feel free to open an issue if something isn't working as expected.

Comment: solid approach, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

- If your template directories are under the `src` folder, as [Derryl Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673191/9115178) said in the previous answer, you need to specify the path location of your assets in the nest-cli.json file.

NOTE:

> The assets must be located in the src folder or they will not be copied.

- If like me your template directories are at the same level as the `src` folder, you also need to update the `sourceRoot` property and the `entryFile` property of the `nest-cli.json` file.

To see what your configuration file should look like, you can download the cli diagram [here](https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli)

---

Here is the archive of my project:

[image]

Here is what my nest-cli.json file looks like

```json
{
  "$schema" : "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot" : ".",
  "compilerOptions" : {
    "assets" : ["config.*.yaml", "assets/**"]
  },
  "entryFile" : "src/main"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a hassle-free way of doing it, the popular [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node)
package does that automatically! `ts-node` is the equivalent to running `node` but for TypeScript projects. If you're going to use `ts-node`, you won't have to compile the TypeScript files and run the `js` file, `ts-node` does that all in the background.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `ts-node` should NOT be used in production, at least not without adjusting it. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581617/is-it-a-bad-practise-to-use-ts-node-in-production

Comment: @A-S the link you posted literally says it can be used in production with the --transpile-only flag

Comment: Some people just like to overcomplicate things that should be simple.

Comment: @Nando - I already wrote it cannot be used as-is in production, and some steps should be taken (I also included an article about it)... How did your comment add any value, other than rephrasing my comment and demotivating me?

Comment: Because it actually can be used as-is in production. I have at least one public API using it now, without any compilation folder. The value my comment adds is to point out the distinction between the objective "can" and your "should".

Answer (score 1):

In my case I added the assets config to copy html files and it worked.

*nest-cli.json*

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": ["**/*.html"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use cp command in the build script :

```
"build": "pnpm i && tsc --build && cp public/legal.html dist/legal.html",
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same situation, coincidentally, mail templates as well. It took me a while to figure this out, but Typescript will absolutely do nothing for you here, you have to fix this outside of Typescript.

You'll also want to use a OS-independent way; most answers thusfar are OS specific (nice until you're moving to production), or are for NestJs.

The solution lies in two **npm packages** (DEV dependencies):

- rimraf (to clean-up)
- copyfiles (to copy files)

Using your preferred package manager:

```bash
pnpm add -D rimraf copyfiles
npm install --save-dev rimraf copyfiles
yarn add -D rimraf copyfiles
```

Then add two "scripts" to your package.json. In my project the target folder is called `"build"`, yours might be called `"dist"`, adjust as needed. Also, this assumes the "templates" folder is in your "src" folder, it could also be in your projects root, again adjust as needed.

```json
"scripts": {
    ...
    "clean": "rimraf build/",
    "copyfiles": "copyfiles -u 1 src/templates/**/* build/"
},
```

At this point, you can test both commands. Using pnpm (I'm sure you can imagine the command for other managers):

```bash
pnpm copy-files
pnpm clean
```

If this worked, you can then go ahead and change your build script, adding the clean step before it, and the copy step after it. Work with your existing build script. In my case it was just calling `tsc`. Which would then look like:

```json
"scripts": {
    ...
    "clean": "rimraf build/",
    "copyfiles": "copyfiles -u 1 src/templates/**/* build/",
    "build": "pnpm clean && tsc && pnpm copyfiles"
}
```

Documentation:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf

Answer (score -3):

Firstly, you add bellow code to **nest-cli.json**:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": ["*.proto"],
    "watchAssets": true
  }
```

And then the most important thing is you have to put the your files inside **/src** directory, not in project root directory.

Comment: You save me. All solution I tried is wrong except you.