# Typescript compiler not saved json in root directory

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have a project in express/typescript and in my root directory backend, the files .json dont save in the folder dist

> tsconfig.json

```
{


"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "lib": ["es2015"]
}
```

> tslint.json

```
  {
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": ["tslint:recommended"],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {
      "no-console": false
    },
    "rulesDirectory": []
  }
```

root Directory

- appsettings.development.json -> This files are not saved inthe dist folder
- appsettings.json -> This files are not saved in the dist folder
- swagger.json -> This files are not saved in the dist folder
- tsconfig.json
- tslint.json
- dist

Directory order:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy non-ts files to dist when building typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306654/how-to-copy-non-ts-files-to-dist-when-building-typescript)

Comment: No, that answer doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what it's supposed to do. Whatever you put on tsconfig.json is used by the Typescript compiler, which compiles ts files to js. It doesn't do anything with other files.

tslint.json has nothing to do with your issue, it's for setting linting rules.

What you want to achieve is usually done by extending your npm scripts with some shell commands like "cp" or by using a bundler like webpack, rollup, etc.