# How to add a PDF in TypeScript build to use it in Firebase Functions?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, nodemailer

I have the following Firebase function which uses nodemailer to send an email with attachment.

```
    await nodemailer.createTransport(transport).sendMail({
        from: from,
        to: studentDto.email,
        subject: subject,
        html: Mail.createInvoice(studentDto, itemDto),
        attachments: [{filename: 'file.pdf', path: './assets/file.pdf'}],
    });
```

The PDF is at `src/assets/file.pdf`. When I run `npm run build` the folder `lib` is created but `assets/file.pdf` is not included.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

How can `file.pdf` be included in the build?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy non-ts files to dist when building typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306654/how-to-copy-non-ts-files-to-dist-when-building-typescript)

Comment: Thx, it helped me understand the issue. But I found another solution which I will post here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Reason

TSC does not include any assets in the build.

## Solution

I uploaded the file to Firebase Storage. There I could copy the public url and use it.